# Redis queue worker module not found

Tags: python, docker, flask, redis, docker-compose

I have `dockrized` container to run a `flask app`. After configuring the `redis` and `rq worker` I am getting the error for `module not found` in the worker task. I am certain this is some path issue, I cant seem to figure out what the correct path should be for my worker to find any of the modules used in my flask app.

Here is what my current project structure looks like:

```
- core-app
  - app.py
  - worker.py
  - dashboard
    - Dockerfile
  - symbol
    - __init__.py
    - symbol.py
  - Dockerfile
  - docker-compose.yml
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.7"
services:

  db:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"

  api:
    image: core-app:latest
    build: .
    command: python -u app.py
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - core_redis

  worker:
      image: core-app:latest
      command: rq worker --path /core-app/ --url redis://core_redis:6379 my_queue
      depends_on:
        - core_redis

  core_redis:
      image: redis:5.0.8-alpine
      ports:
        - "6379:6379"
      volumes:
        - ./redis:/data

  dashboard:
      build: ./dashboard
      image: dashboard
      container_name: dashboard
      ports:
        - 9181:9181
      command: rq-dashboard -H core_redis
      depends_on:
        - core_redis
```

`worker.py`

```
from symbol import symbol

def run_symbol_worker_task(symbol_id):
    print('starting worker tasks for: ' + symbol_id) # in place of actual logging
    symbol.some_func_here()
    return {symbol_id: 'task complete'}
```

`app.py`

```
redis_conn = Redis(host='core_redis', port=6379, db=0)
q = Queue('my_queue', connection=redis_conn)
q.empty()

job = q.enqueue(run_symbol_worker_task, 'key')
print(job.get_status())
```

Error that I am getting is:

```
worker_1      | Traceback (most recent call last):
worker_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 822, in perform_job
worker_1      |     rv = job.perform()
worker_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 605, in perform
worker_1      |     self._result = self._execute()
worker_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 611, in _execute
worker_1      |     return self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
worker_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 200, in func
worker_1      |     return import_attribute(self.func_name)
worker_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/utils.py", line 155, in import_attribute
worker_1      |     module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
worker_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
worker_1      |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
worker_1      |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
worker_1      |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
worker_1      |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
worker_1      |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
worker_1      |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
worker_1      |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
worker_1      |   File "/core-app/worker.py", line 5, in <module>
worker_1      |     from symbol import symbol
worker_1      | ImportError: cannot import name 'symbol' from 'symbol' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/symbol.py)
```

I do not understand why is the path not setup to look for in my root directory, rather it looks into `usr/local/lib/python3.7`..

Comment: Does your project contain a file named `symbol.py`?

Comment: Also, that path is inside the docker image, not on your local machine

Comment: I see, did you mean to `import symbols` with an "s"?

Comment: @jordanm yes, I have made the edit.

Comment: I see the problem with the `symbol` package, the `worker` cannot seem to map it.

Comment: You can't name your module `symbol` because there is a built-in module named "symbol"